# MySQL Multitable Query Problem

Tags: sql, mysql, cartesian-product

I have a problem querying multiple tables in `MySQL` and am currently at my wits end.

I have unique `ID`s in each table, and am using an `INNER JOIN` to combine them; I am quite new to `SQL` and this may be the wrong method, hence me posting here:

Query:

```
SELECT res.UserID, res.QuizID, res.QuizResult, u.UserID, u.UserLogin, q.QuizID, q.QuizName, q.QuizFile
FROM results res
INNER JOIN users u ON (res.UserID = u.UserID) 
INNER JOIN quiz q ON (res.QuizID = q.QuizID)
```

Table `users` contains

```
UserID
UserLogin
UserPass
```

Table `quiz` contains

```
QuizID
QuizName
QuizFile
```

Table `results` contains

```
UserID
QuizID
QuizResults
```

Can anybody please tell me why I am getting a cartesian product, and how I should go about fixing it?

Comment: What do you _want_ your query to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT res.UserID, res.QuizID, res.QuizResult, u.UserID, u.UserLogin, q.QuizID, q.QuizName, q.QuizFile FROM results as res INNER JOIN users as u ON res.UserID = u.UserID INNER JOIN quiz as q ON res.QuizID = q.QuizID
```

A different way to realize something like an INNER JOIN is this:+

```
SELECT res.UserID, res.QuizID, res.QuizResult, u.UserID, u.UserLogin, q.QuizID, q.QuizName, q.QuizFile 
FROM results as res,users as u ,quiz as q 
WHERE res.UserID = u.UserID 
AND res.QuizID = q.QuizID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this query still produces cartesian, any other ideas please?

Comment: hm.. then just tell us what u exactly expect as the result... As far as I can tell, these querys should not produce an certesian product...